# Mouse and keyboard temporarily freeze when pluged through an usb hub

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse, usb-hub

I have a Windows 10 computer with a MSI B450 TOMAHAWK MAX motherboard. If I plug my usb keyboard and usb mouse to the computer via an usb hub, both the mouse and keyboard will freeze (not respond or respond with a lag) for a second or less every few minutes or even more frequently. If I plug those directly to the computer, there is no freezing. Those freezes only appear to be affecting mouse and keyboard, the computer works normally when they happen.

I've tried different mouses, keyboards and different hubs (powered and not), but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I wasn't able to recreate the problem on another computer using the same usb hub, mouse and keyboard.

I've tried disabling "Legacy support" in BIOS and "Selective Suspension" in Windows power settings, but it doesn't appear to make any difference.

Any idea what could be causing the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Just to rule it out, did you try to update (or downgrade) your BIOS/UEFI firmware and motherboard/USB-related drivers, e.g. switch between MSI and Windows (device manager or Windows Update) stock drivers? And as you did not explicitly mention it, did you try all available USB ports? Selective USB device suspension or a bad hub/cable (high voltage drop) would have been my 1. guess as well, but you rules that out already.

Comment: I've tried various USB ports on the motherboard, but id didn't make a difference. At one point I have updated the BIOS to resolve some other issue, but it didn't seem to affect the usb hub problem (it happened before and it happened after). I haven't tried changing drivers, but I remember being unable to install MSI chipset drivers before (I've used stock Windows before, but then managed to install drivers directly from AMD). I'll check if I can do something about the USB drivers.

Comment: The recommendation to disable Selective Suspension fixed my issue, thanks! (Power & Sleep > Additional Power Settings > Change Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings > USB settings > USB selective suspend setting > Disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the chipset drivers seems to have resolved the issue (no more mouse and keyboard randomly freezing).

Sometimes the usb hub stops working, but that looks like an actual issue with the hub (unrelated to the freezing). It happens very rarely and doesn't sound worrying (replugging the hub fixes it).

---

Edit: Installing AMD drivers changed the power profile and the now profile had Selective Suspension turned on. The issue was returning, but turning off Selective Suspension on the new profile appears to have helped.

TLDR; Try installing/updating chipset drivers and make sure Selective Suspension is turned off in the selected power profile afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that doesn't work. I have a 2020 ASus ROG Zephrus G14 laptop and I have a blackweb usb 3.0 hub plugged into the USB A port on the right side. I also have a hard drive mount plugged into the other USB A port. The hub adds 4 additional USB 3.0 slots. I have a cheap logitech k400+ keyboard plugged into 1 slot and logitech G602 mouse plugged into the other slots. The remaining 2 slots are open. Whenver i plug in a hard drive or a usb thumb stick my logitech G602 mouse freezes up. Using the keyboard's track pad works for a while but then it starts unresponding when i try to either open up pictures, or videos on the thumbdrive/hard drive.

I've updated all the chip sets and turned off selective suspension but nothing seems to work.  I don't have any adapters to use the USB-C slots so I'm wondering what I can do to keep freeze up from happening.

My only speculation is that the bandwith on that one USB A 3.0 slot is being overloaded due to so many devices plugged in to one data lane. Though it shouldn't really affect it.

Depending on if you have a laptop or a desktop you may need to plug in your hub using a usb to pci adapter, that is if you have a pci lane open. For me I don't have such an option as I am using a laptop.