# Keyboard and mouse plugged into monitor USB hub sporadically cutting out

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse, usb-hub

I have a monitor with an integrated USB hub, which connects to my desktop via a USB A to USB B cable.  All my previous Windows computers have worked without a hitch, but my recently acquired desktop does not play nice.  When the keyboard is plugged into the hub, random keystrokes will get missed, and occasionally it will behave like the key was held down for a few seconds.  When the mouse is plugged in, it will randomly stop responding for a second.

I do not see this behavior with any other computer, nor do I get it in the BIOS on this computer, so I think it's a Windows issue.  Disabling Selective Suspension in the power settings, as in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1604111/mouse-and-keyboard-temporarily-freeze-when-pluged-through-an-usb-hub) helped briefly, but the problem persists.

I do not see these issues if I plug in the keyboard and mouse directly into the desktop box.

### Update

Disabling the power setting under the USB devices did not change the situation.  Also, the behavior is not consistent.  Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it behaves worse than normal.  Unplugging it and replugging it in does not change the behavior, but waking it from sleep or restarting can make it act better or worse.

Comment: This behavior might be due to the hub. Try an external hub to test. Yes, the integrated hub works on on other PC's, but might not on *this* one.

Comment: Try going into device manager, then expand you USB controllers, find the one that your hub is using, then double click(right click -> properties), then go to power management and finally uncheck "allow computer to turn off...." this could help. Also check if the usb port you are using can pump enough amps for you devices.